# How do I create a precompiled header from inside a clang-based project?

Tags: clang, llvm, precompiled-headers

I am working on a clang-based tool and I need to be able to create precompiled headers at certain times. Where can I find information about how to make one? The clang/LLVM documentation lacks any examples on how to do this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you are using `CMake`, Use [`cotire`](https://github.com/sakra/cotire) will help.